# NoSuchFieldException: ALL_OBJECT_POOL error while trying to type convert a custom object in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gson, android-room

I am trying to write a simple object type converter for a custom object I made in Android Studio Java. My Object is called MapAnnotationObject, and holds three ArrayLists consisting of the following objects: Markers, Circles and PolyLines, all of which are drawables on a GoogleMaps instance:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Circle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MapAnnotationObject implements Serializable {

    ArrayList<Marker> markerList;
    ArrayList<Circle> circleList;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>> polyLineList;

    public MapAnnotationObject(){
        markerList = new ArrayList<>();
        circleList = new ArrayList<>();
        polyLineList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addToMarkerList(Marker marker){markerList.add(marker);}
    public void addToCircleList(Circle circle){circleList.add(circle);}
    public void addToPolyLineList(ArrayList<LatLng> coords){polyLineList.add(coords);}

    public ArrayList<Marker> getMarkerList(){return markerList;}
    public ArrayList<Circle> getCircleList(){return circleList;}
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>> getPolyLineList(){return polyLineList;}

    public void removeFromMarkerList(Marker marker){markerList.remove(marker);}
    public Circle removeFromCircleList(Circle circle){
        circleList.remove(circle);
        return circle;
    }

}
```

I would like to store this Object in a Room database, for which I have written an Object Convertor utilising Gson:

```
import androidx.room.TypeConverter;
import androidx.room.TypeConverters;

import com.example.coursework_2.objects.GeofenceObject;
import com.example.coursework_2.objects.MapAnnotationObject;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class MapAnnotationObjectConverter {

    static Gson gson = new Gson();

    @TypeConverter
    public static MapAnnotationObject stringToMapAnnotationObject(String data){
        if (data == null){
            return new MapAnnotationObject();
        }

        Type mapObjectType = new TypeToken<MapAnnotationObject>() {}.getType();

        return gson.fromJson(data, mapObjectType);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String mapAnnotationObjectToString(MapAnnotationObject mapAnnotationObject){
        return gson.toJson(mapAnnotationObject);
    }
}
```

And the following column in the database to store the object:

```
    @ColumnInfo(name = "map_annotations")
    @TypeConverters(MapAnnotationObjectConverter.class)
    public MapAnnotationObject map_annotations;
```

However whenever I try and add to the Room database, I get the following error:
`java.lang.AssertionError: AssertionError (GSON 2.8.5): java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: ALL_OBJECT_POOL`
Which Logcat identifies as occurring on this line in my Type Converter:
`return gson.toJson(mapAnnotationObject);`
I'm at a real loss as to what is causing the problem and how I would go about fixing it, any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

I have a second custom object being implemented into the database that utilises this exact same code with no problems at all, so i have looked into potentially finding a way to convert all of the ArrayList's separately, but am unsure if this si the correct course of action or not.

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.AssertionError: AssertionError (GSON 2.8.5): java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: ALL_OBJECT_POOL

This looks like a known issue in older Gson versions where code shrinking tools (such as R8 which is configured for Android builds by default) rename enum constants, which causes Gson to be unable to find them. This has been fixed by [this pull request](https://github.com/google/gson/pull/1495) in Gson 2.8.8. Please try using that Gson version, or even better the latest version to benefit from other improvements as well.

Some additional tips:

- Make sure you have configured R8 properly; otherwise you will probably run into other issues as well, see [Gson's android-proguard-example](https://github.com/google/gson/tree/main/examples/android-proguard-example) (which also applies to R8), and also the [R8 FAQ](https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/refs/heads/main/compatibility-faq.md#troubleshooting)
- Gson's `TypeToken` is only needed for generic types such as `List<T>`; you can simplify your code to:

  ```java
  return gson.fromJson(data, MapAnnotationObject.class);
  ```

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're encountering might be related to the Gson library trying to serialize the MapAnnotationObject and facing difficulties due to the internal structure of the object (containing ArrayLists and other complex structures).

One solution could be to write custom TypeAdapters for Gson to handle the serialization and deserialization of your MapAnnotationObject. Here's an example of how you could implement custom TypeAdapters for MapAnnotationObject:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MapAnnotationObjectTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<MapAnnotationObject> {

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, MapAnnotationObject value) throws IOException {
        out.beginObject();
        out.name("markerList");
        writeList(out, value.getMarkerList());
        out.name("circleList");
        writeList(out, value.getCircleList());
        out.name("polyLineList");
        writeNestedList(out, value.getPolyLineList());
        out.endObject();
    }

    @Override
    public MapAnnotationObject read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        MapAnnotationObject mapAnnotationObject = new MapAnnotationObject();
        in.beginObject();
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            String name = in.nextName();
            switch (name) {
                case "markerList":
                    mapAnnotationObject.setMarkerList(readList(in, Marker.class));
                    break;
                case "circleList":
                    mapAnnotationObject.setCircleList(readList(in, Circle.class));
                    break;
                case "polyLineList":
                    mapAnnotationObject.setPolyLineList(readNestedList(in, LatLng.class));
                    break;
                default:
                    in.skipValue();
            }
        }
        in.endObject();
        return mapAnnotationObject;
    }

    private <T> void writeList(JsonWriter out, ArrayList<T> list) throws IOException {
        out.beginArray();
        for (T item : list) {
            gson.toJson(item, item.getClass(), out);
        }
        out.endArray();
    }

    private <T> ArrayList<T> readList(JsonReader in, Class<T> type) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        in.beginArray();
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            list.add(gson.fromJson(in, type));
        }
        in.endArray();
        return list;
    }

    private <T> void writeNestedList(JsonWriter out, ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> nestedList) throws IOException {
        out.beginArray();
        for (ArrayList<T> list : nestedList) {
            writeList(out, list);
        }
        out.endArray();
    }

    private <T> ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> readNestedList(JsonReader in, Class<T> type) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> nestedList = new ArrayList<>();
        in.beginArray();
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            nestedList.add(readList(in, type));
        }
        in.endArray();
        return nestedList;
    }
}

public class MapAnnotationObjectConverter {

    static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(MapAnnotationObject.class, new MapAnnotationObjectTypeAdapter())
            .create();

    @TypeConverter
    public static MapAnnotationObject stringToMapAnnotationObject(String data){
        if (data == null){
            return new MapAnnotationObject();
        }

        Type mapObjectType = new TypeToken<MapAnnotationObject>() {}.getType();

        return gson.fromJson(data, mapObjectType);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String mapAnnotationObjectToString(MapAnnotationObject mapAnnotationObject){
        return gson.toJson(mapAnnotationObject);
    }
}
```

This way, you're explicitly defining how Gson should serialize and deserialize your complex object, taking care of the ArrayLists and their contents. This might resolve the NoSuchFieldException issue you're facing.